Can't read data from firebase from fragment
I'm taking my first steps in Android Studio. I have a database in Firebase that stores users information, each entry is identified by email address, for some reason, I can't retrieve the entry data in [1], [1] code runs in a class that extends Fragment. while similar code in the function of another class that extends AppCompatActivity.
Any idea what could be the root cause?
Any connection to the fragment?
Any help would be greatly appreciated
10x
[1]
   read_Data(indx, new UserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(User user) {
            if (user != null) {
                playerdata = user;
            } else {
                showToast("something failed");
            }
        }
    });


private void read_Data(String email, UserCallback callback) {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    Query query = reference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).limitToFirst(1);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            System.out.println("onDataChange! ");
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                System.out.println("snapshot exists! ");
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    callback.onCallback(user);
                    return;
                }
            }
            callback.onCallback(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            System.out.println("On cancelled! ");
            callback.onCallback(null); // Pass null in case of error
        }

    });
}

I tried to add call thread.sleep(2000) after calling [1] function, thought it might help because addListenerForSingleValueEvent is async, but it didn't

"Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example." and Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example

On Stack Overflow, do not require the reader to use links to external information. Everything should be in the question itself so future readers always have immediate access to it. If you have code, copy and paste it into the question so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Ack, 10x.  Edited my Q

As far as I can see, the playerdata variable is defined as a global variable. When you assign the user object to the playerdata object, using the following line of code:
playerdata = user;

It doesn't mean that you'll be able to use it anywhere in the class. Even if you are using a callback, the value becomes available only when the operation of reading the data is complete. The solution is always the same. Any code that needs data from the database, needs to be inside the onDataChange or  onCallback methods or be called from there. Since you're using Java, a better solution would be to use a LiveData object, because it can be observed.
An even better solution, if you understand Kotlin, would be to use Kotlin Coroutines.

Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
